# php cURL - Post form with hidden field

Tags: php, curl, hidden-field

I'm trying to access a login form via curl. The problem is that the form have 2 hidden fields. One of those has a value and the other doesn't.

Something like this:

```
 <form name=form id=form method=POST action="login.php">
  <input type=text name=user id=user value="">
  <input type=password name=pass id=pass>
  <input type=submit value="OK" id=sendButton name="sendButton">
  <input type=hidden name=pass2>
  <input type=hidden name=token value="7b8b7d712273aa254e03ea04a30322ab">
</form>
```

The value of token is changed at every refresh.
Once is posted, Live http headers gave me this:

```
user=test&pass=&login=OK&pass2=7c7e36071354b4ecde365b315ffa4406&token=
```

As you can see pass2 now is filled and token is not. Why is that?

I tried to get the token value before posting and send with the parameters. But when i post the value of token is changed.

Here's how i did it:

```
$url = 'http://www.myurl.com/login.php';

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if($tag->getAttribute('name') === 'token') {
         $token = $tag->getAttribute('value');
    }
}

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if($tag->getAttribute('name') === 'pass2') {
         $pass2 = $tag->getAttribute('value');
    }
}

$com = 'OK';
$postdata = 'user='.$user.'&pass='.$pass.'&sendButton='.$com.'&pass2='.$pass2.'&token='.$token;

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;
```

Well, not working. 
If the value of pass2 field is generated after the post as i mentioned what live http returned.. Is it possible that to be the problem? If so, is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Probably some javascript is involved, To mimic that with curl you would need to track down and re-implement the javascript code.

Comment: @Steve how can i track down the javascript?